# IIS7 two directories, one site

Tags: iis, virtualization, directory

I have one site www.mysite.com where I got an application program and now we're going to put our web site here too.

The problem is that the application is untouchable, and want to keep it out from the web site team.

This is the image of what I would like to do:

Server data,
Applicantion:
*C:\myapplication\app.php

C:\myapplication\appfolder\index.html*

Web:
*C:\myweb\index.html

C:\myweb\webfolder\index.html*

Access from the web,
Applicantion:
*www.mysite.com\app.php

www.mysite.com\appfolder\index.html*

Web:
*www.mysite.com\index.html

www.mysite.com\webfolder\index.html*

I know there are virtual folders, but I don't want to add folders one by one...
There are files on the root of the website for the app as for the website.
I would create 2 different FTP accounts, one for *C:\myapplication* and one for *C:\myweb*

It is possible to do this?

I'm using Windows 2008 R2 with IIS and PHP

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea (although untested):

1) Create virtual folder for your php app (I know, you have said you do not want it)

2) Using URL-Rewrite module rewrite urls (e.g. `/app.php -> /virtual/app.php`).

Your visitors should see normal URL while behind it will be located differently.

You can replace virtual folder by symlink or directory junction if you want -- but it has some drawbacks as such symlinked folder will be physical part of website (at least on server) and can be overwritten by mistake (unless you setup proper access permissions).

The possible problem with this approach is that you have to rely on how well your php app is written -- it may incorrectly calculate paths for include/require and other file-related operations (in one place they may use REAL file location (e.g. C:\myapplication\app.php), in another place they may refer to the path as seen by website (SERVER_ROOT), e.g. C:\myweb\virtual\app.php) -- you really have to test it.

Comment: It seems that is now way to virtually merge 2 folders on Windows 2008 R2, just create symbolic links to each files and folders, maybe creating an automated batch file to do it... I was hoping something like Unionfs but seems that it doesn't exists for Windows.

Comment: So .. what is stopping you from doing the suggested symbolic links path? With the help of [Shell Link Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) you can do this VERY quickly. Just keep in mind, that when deploying your "Web" part you may overwrite or even delete the symbolic links (it really depends how you do the deployment) as from user/dev point of view all these files/folders belonging to the same app.

Comment: I just needed to merge virtually two directories, specially files, but finally I decided to use virtual folders from IIS, added each folder from the web site, if they add another folder I will have to add another virtual folder. It was the faster solution for now...